# How to display Observable?

Tags: angular, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

**This is the interface of the product**

```
export interface Product{
    id?:string,
    name:string,
    price:string;
    quantity:string;
    tags:Tags[];
    description:string;
    files: File[];
}
```

**In my home.component.ts file I have this**

```
 export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private store:Store<fromRoot.AppState>
  ) { }

  products$!: Observable<Product[]>;
  products_list! :Product[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new productActions.LoadProducts());
```

**^^^^This function calls the loadproducts$ from effect.ts**

```
    this.products$ = this.store.pipe(select(fromProduct.getCreatedProducts));

  }
}
```

**products$ is an obseravale now to display this, I use Async | json**
**.Below is my html code.**

```
<div *ngFor = "let p of products$ | async">
   <h1>
    {{p.name}}
</h1>
</div>
```

**Here I am attesting action.ts**

```
export enum UserActionTypes{

    LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS = '[User] Load Created Products',
    LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = '[User] Load Created Products Success',
    LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS_FAIL = '[User] Load Created Products Fail'
    
}
export class LoadProducts implements Action{
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS
}
export class LoadProductsSuccess implements Action{
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS
    constructor(public payload:Product[]){}
}
export class LoadProductsFail implements Action{
    readonly type = UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS_FAIL
    constructor(public payload:string){}
}

export type action = LoadProducts | LoadProductsSuccess | LoadProductsFail ;
```

**Here is my product.reducer.ts**

```
export interface SoldProductState extends EntityState<Product>{
    selectedProductId: string,
    loading:boolean,
    loaded:boolean,
    error:string
}

export const productAdapter:EntityAdapter<Product> = createEntityAdapter<Product>({
    selectId:Product=>Product.id
});
export const defaultProduct:SoldProductState={
    ids:[],
    entities:{},
    selectedProductId:"",
    loading:false,
    loaded:false,
    error:""
    
}

export const initialState = productAdapter.getInitialState(defaultProduct);

export function productReducer(
    state = initialState,
    action:productActions.action
    ):SoldProductState{
```

**Here is my LoadCreatedProduct**

```
    switch(action.type){
        case productActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS:{
            return {
                ...state,
                loading:true,
                loaded:false
            };
        }
```

**Here is my LoadCreatedProductSuccess**

```
        case productActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:{
            return productAdapter.addMany(action.payload,{
                ...state,
                entities:{},
                loaded:true,
                loading:false
            });
        }
        default:{
            return state;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here I am adding the effect.ts**

```
    @Effect()
    loadproducts$:Observable<Action> = this.action$.pipe(
        ofType<productActions.LoadProducts>(
            productActions.UserActionTypes.LOAD_CREATED_PRODUCTS
        ),
        mergeMap((actions:productActions.LoadProducts)=>
            this.product_service.getCreatedProducts().pipe(
                map(
                    (products:Product[])=>
                        new productActions.LoadProductsSuccess(products)
                ),
                catchError(err=>of(new productActions.LoadProductsFail(err)))
            ))
    )
```

Now, If I load the page every thing is displayed properly as shown below
[image: Like this]

If I navigate to another page and comes back the list doubles as shown below[image: like this]

If I visit another page n times the list will be displayed n times.

But if I reload the page it works fine.
I am a beginner and do not know how to tackle this problem.
I hope I am able to explain my problem.
Thanking you.

Comment: Could you please include the code of `productActions.LoadProducts()` action handler within the `reducer` file?

Comment: @AmerYousuf I have added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`addMany` (productAdapter.addMany) append the new items to the already existing items, which causes duplication in your data.

use `setAll` instead of `addMany` to replace all the existing items with the new ones: